# vb.net Dynamic gui multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a loop of code that I want to execute, but I want each pass to be its own thread so the execution is quick.  Within this pass I have several GUI items.  Heres what I have tried:

```
sub somesub()
Dim w As WaitCallback = New WaitCallback(AddressOf WorkerDoWork)
for 1 to 10
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(w, i)
next
end sub
sub WorkerDoWork(i as integer)
dim x as string = drpitem.Selecteditem
end sub
```

I have also tried:

```
sub somesub()
Dim threads As New List(Of Thread)()
for 1 to 10
threads.Add(New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf WorkerDoWork)))
threads(i).Start()
next
end sub
sub WorkerDoWork(i as integer)
dim x as string = drpitem.Selecteditem
end sub
```

both error on drpitem about crossthreading.  How can I do a dynamic multithreaded loop without erroring out.  Also something interesting to note, is I can use background workers in the GUI successfully without erroring, but I don't know how to use background workers dynamically.

Edit:

After reading your suggestion marco, I have came up with the answer

```
sub somesub()
Dim w As WaitCallback = New WaitCallback(AddressOf WorkerDoWork)
for 1 to 10
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(w, i)
next
end sub
sub WorkerDoWork(i as integer)
dim x as string
invoke(sub() x = drpitem.Selecteditem)
end sub
```

The key is to use invoke where it breaks and it will work.

Comment: Look here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334425/vb-net-delegates-and-invoke-can-somebody-explain-these-to-me

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you are creating a thread and then accessing an object which is being handled in another one. Have a look here:

> [VB.NET Delegates and Invoke - can somebody explain these to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334425/vb-net-delegates-and-invoke-can-somebody-explain-these-to-me)